Kernel panic - not syncing: Unable to initialise architected timer : unable to boot Android 14 with qemu-system-aarch64 on Ubuntu 24.04 X64 bit
I want to emulate Android 14 by KonstaKang using qemu-system-aarch64 and as model virt on Ubuntu 24.04 x64 bit installed on my PC (Intel I9 + RTX 2080 ti).
I've chosen the parameters to boot it,according with the files provided by that version of Android,that you can find here :
https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/AOSP14/
This is the command issued with the parameters embedded :
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -m 2048 \
    -cpu cortex-a72 \
    -M virt,gic-version=2 \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/local/share/qemu/edk2-aarch64-code.fd \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/local/share/qemu/edk2-arm-vars.fd \
    -kernel /mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Linux/lineage-21.0-20240618-UNOFFICIAL-KonstaKANG-rpi4-atv/boot/Image \
    -append 'console=ttyAMA0,38400 keep_bootcon earlycon=pl011,0x9000000 androidboot.hardware=ranchu root=/dev/vdd1' \
    -drive file=/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Linux/lineage-21.0-20240618-UNOFFICIAL-KonstaKANG-rpi4-atv/lineage-21.0-20240618-UNOFFICIAL-KonstaKANG-rpi4-atv.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk \
    -device virtio-gpu-pci \
    -device qemu-xhci \
    -device usb-kbd \
    -device usb-mouse \
    -netdev user,id=mynet \
    -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet \
    -serial stdio \
    -no-reboot \
    -d guest_errors \
    -smp cores=4 \
    -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci,addr=0x5 \
    -device usb-mouse,bus=xhci.0 \
    -device usb-kbd,bus=xhci.0

Where I found the kernel "Image" ? here :
https://dlupload.com/filedetail/377203177
This is the boot log :
EFI stub: Booting Linux Kernel...
EFI stub: EFI_RNG_PROTOCOL unavailable
EFI stub: Generating empty DTB
EFI stub: Exiting boot services...
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.6.36-g01aac93821d2-v8 (kleaf@build-host) (Android (11368308, +pgo, +bolt, +lto, +mlgo, based on r510928) clang version 18.0.0 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 477610d4d0d988e69dbc3fae4fe86bff3f07f2b5), LLD 18.0.0) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul  2 09:02:32 UTC 2024
[    0.000000] KASLR disabled due to lack of seed
[    0.000000] printk: debug: skip boot console de-registration.
[    0.000000] earlycon: pl11 at MMIO 0x0000000009000000 (options '')
[    0.000000] printk: bootconsole [pl11] enabled
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.7 by EDK II
[    0.000000] efi: SMBIOS 3.0=0xbfed0000 MEMATTR=0xbd0a0018 ACPI 2.0=0xbc6f0018 MEMRESERVE=0xbcb43f18 
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    empty
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] NoSplit zone start for each node
[    0.000000] NoMerge zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000bc76ffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bc770000-0x00000000bcb3ffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bcb40000-0x00000000bfe1ffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bfe20000-0x00000000bfeaffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bfeb0000-0x00000000bfebffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bfec0000-0x00000000bffdffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bffe0000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x00000000bbc00000 on node -1
[    0.000000] Failed to find device node for boot cpu
[    0.000000] missing boot CPU MPIDR, not enabling secondaries
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 31 pages/cpu s87016 r8192 d31768 u126976
[    0.000000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v2
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v3a
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v4
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-BHB
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 1742098
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM errata 1165522, 1319367, or 1530923
[    0.000000] alternatives: applying boot alternatives
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyAMA0,38400 keep_bootcon earlycon=pl011,0x9000000 androidboot.hardware=ranchu root=/dev/vdd1 androidboot.serialno=10000000abcd1234 androidboot.btmacaddr=11:22:33:44:55:66
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 516096
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:all(zero), heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 2008408K/2097152K available (19328K kernel code, 2374K rwdata, 7612K rodata, 1792K init, 1192K bss, 80552K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 56269 entries in 220 pages
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocated 220 pages with 5 groups
[    0.000000] trace event string verifier disabled
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000]  Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] rcu: srcu_init: Setting srcu_struct sizes based on contention.
[    0.000000] timer_probe: no matching timers found
[    0.000000] Kernel panic - not syncing: Unable to initialise architected timer.
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.6.36-g01aac93821d2-v8 #1
[    0.000000] Call trace:
[    0.000000]  dump_backtrace+0x104/0x124
[    0.000000]  show_stack+0x28/0x38
[    0.000000]  dump_stack_lvl+0x58/0x78
[    0.000000]  dump_stack+0x20/0x30
[    0.000000]  panic+0x148/0x35c
[    0.000000]  time_init+0x68/0x6c
[    0.000000]  start_kernel+0x1b8/0x3d0
[    0.000000]  __primary_switched+0xc4/0xd0
[    0.000000] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
[    0.000000] Reboot failed -- System halted

Any idea about how to fix it ?
